# MySQL auto increment plus alphanumerics in one column

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am new to MySQL coming from Oracle. I have a requirement to create a table with the primary key in one column but with the following format.

`X-A` letter stating the country of origin e.g. `S` for Spain, `Z` for Zimbabwe e.tc (we have five countries of origins only)

`YYYYMMDD` - Date in that format,
`9999` - 4 digit office code.
`9999999` - 7 right padded sequence number from a sequence in Oracle (auto increment in MySQL)
This gives me a primary key like `Z2010013150110000001` as the primary key.

My question is how do I generate the part of `9999999` in MySQL. In Oracle it would have been

```
select 'Z'||to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')|| 5011||cust_id.nextval from dual;
```

Comment: Somebody doesn't understand normalization...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html) can't be just part of a field, so a single column might be a wash.  So how about:

```
CREATE TABLE xxxxx (
id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
rest_of_that_key char(xx) not null,
// other goodies
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Then you can `SELECT CONCAT(rest_of_that_key, LPAD(id, 7, '0')) AS full_key FROM xxxxx`.

---

Or even better, so you can use those office codes and dates to filter data with:

```
CREATE TABLE xxxxx (
id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
country_code char(1) not null,
sysdate date not null,
office_code smallint unsigned not null,
// other goodies
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY country_code (country_code)
// etc, index the useful stuff
);
```

Then you can use `SELECT CONCAT(country_code, DATE_FORMAT(sysdate, '%Y%m%d'), office_code, LPAD(id, 7, '0')) AS full_key FROM xxxxx` and even throw in a `WHERE office_code = 1256 AND sysdate >= '2010-01-01'` without having to somehow parse that huge string.

If you really need that huge string as a single-field primary key, you'll have manually increment things yourself.  I still wouldn't recommend doing it though, MySQL *really* likes its PKs to be numeric.