# Auto Increment table id with mixture of letters and numbers

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I was wondering if they is a way to auto increment an id with a mixture of letters and numbers?

lets say I have a table like

table name: items

```
pid   name 
1     coca cola
2     fanta
```

I wanted to make the `pid` auto increment and in it it should automatic generate letters and numbers without me having to add them myself.

If you know how this can be done please give me a clear answer or a link to somewhere, where I might find the answer.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648253/automatically-add-letters-in-front-of-an-auto-increment-fieild

Comment: @Jonnny I did this 

`UNIQUE KEY `Fake_ID` (`Fake_ID`,`ProdID`)` will that generate a mixture of letters and numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If you  want do this, create a new field (e.g: `fake_id`) then use php's [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid) function.

- An autoincrement field is of integer type, so adding a letter there violates the constraint.

Comment: I have some questions about this unique. My reason i want to make my pid a mixture of letters and numbers is so that in my url no one can guess my pid. So added this new field fix id. what will be the `type` and will this auto fill out each columns?

Comment: as i said you can create fake_id column and use it instead of id

Comment: okay I created a column called fake_id but they is nothing in it, so how will this work please.

Comment: this fake_id type is var and the index is unique and it is auto_increment. please create me if I am wrong

Comment: you didnt see my answer ? i have give you the link to create uniquid function , and you can also use it unique by many various methods.

Comment: i saw your answer. so i did this `UNIQUE KEY Fake_ID (Fake_ID,pid)`