# How do I add a autoincrement primary key in php

Tags: php, auto-increment

I have my database with table test. It has a primary id "Id" which is auto-increment. Now the id is in the format 1,2,3.. . .Is it possible to store the primary Id as A1,A2,A3 .. . . and so on(with auto-increment).

Comment: php is not a database. Do you use mysql as your database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically add  letters in front of an auto-increment fieild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648253/automatically-add-letters-in-front-of-an-auto-increment-fieild)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL auto increment plus alphanumerics in one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380923/mysql-auto-increment-plus-alphanumerics-in-one-column)

Comment: Depends entirely on what you're expecting `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and so on to be? For all we know that might just be 161, 162 and 163 in hexadecimal... (probably isn't but *could* be)

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch that id in A1,A2,A3

```
 SELECT concat('A',id) FROM table_name;
```

You cant create that of primary key format in **mysql**